# Conditionally choose data from different columns based of data in another column

Tags: excel, function

I'm trying to build an Excel formula that will search a given cell for a certain character in a specific order, and then select the specific data as per that.

```
Eg:
Col A        Col B       Col C
---------    --------    -------
FIGUNLPKG    1/1/2015    1/15/2015   ' select from B
REUNLPKG     1/1/2015    1/15/2015   ' select from B
REIR         1/1/2015    1/15/2015   ' select from C
MCUNLPKG     1/1/2015    1/15/2015   ' select from B
REIRAWC      1/1/2015    1/15/2015   ' select from C
```

Now, I want that:

- if `Col A` contains `UNLPKG` then it will select data from `Col B`
- if `Col A` contains `IR` then it will select data from `Col C`.

Also, I have two more scenario, like if the Col A contains - FIGUNLPKG, BAIR then it should select the data from Col C instead of Col B. And if the Col A contains something which don't match our criteria then it will by default select Col B data.

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting and title a bit in order to clarify the question. I hope my edit correctly reflect your intent. If not you can rollback the edit.

Comment: thank you so much jpw for editing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data starts at row 2

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("UNLPKG",A2),0)>0,B2,IF(IFERROR(FIND("IR",A2),0)>0,C2,""))
```

Comment: Now, I have two more scenario, like if the Col A contains  - FIGUNLPKG, BAIR then it should select the data from Col C instead of Col B. And if the Col A contains something which don't match our criteria then it will by default select Col B data.

Comment: perhaps try
    =IF(IFERROR(FIND("FIGUNLPKG",A3),0)>0,C3,IF(IFERROR(FIND("UNLPKG",A3),0)>0,B3,IF(IFERROR(FIND("IR",A3),0)>0,C3,"")))

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple `FIND()` function do the trick?
Unless of course, if you have a much more complex table, then you will need to build a VLookUp table.
[image: Simple FIND() function]